# How to fix "too many values to unpack" in flask using python-requests

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm setting up my pi to post a picture and process it on an external server but it returns `too many values to unpack` error.

I have tried the code using the `python` command and it works but when I want to use the code is flask it didn't work.

This is the process picture code

```
def process_picture(self):
    url = 'http://url.here'
    file = {'file', open('picture/pic.jpg', 'rb')}
    r = requests.post(url, auth=HTTPBasicAuth('user', 'password'), files=file)
```

and this is the error that I got

```
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 801, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "<stdin>", line 94, in run
  File "<stdin>", line 45, in read_temp
  File "<stdin>", line 76, in process_picture
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 116, in post
    return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 60, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 519, in request
    prep = self.prepare_request(req)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 462, in prepare_request
    hooks=merge_hooks(request.hooks, self.hooks),
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 316, in prepare
    self.prepare_body(data, files, json)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 504, in prepare_body
    (body, content_type) = self._encode_files(files, data)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 141, in _encode_files
    for (k, v) in files:
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

If the code is correct, r should equal to `<Response [200]>`

Answer (score 3):

I think `files` needs to be a dictionary (i.e. `{k:v}`), and you are initializing a set (`{x,y}`), so just change:

```
file = {'file', open('picture/pic.jpg', 'rb')}
```

to

```
file = {'file': open('picture/pic.jpg', 'rb')}
```

Comment: Yes! I also caught this error just now! Been trying to fix this for the last 2 hours and after I posted it on SO, I saw it immediately. Thank you!
I also changed my code to `file = {"file": open("picture/pic.jpg", "rb")}` using a double quote instead of a single quote